# How to get Advanced Data Sets for only one gps point

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I started exploring HERE maps few days back and I want to get road specify data (tunnel, bridge, overpass, underpass, speed limit) like the one returned using "Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets" after using specific layer. I see that this returns list of all the points that belong to particular tile.
But just want to for gps points that my path has and not on an  area. Is it possible using any HERE maps api or any manipulations to the above API or any other WAR?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get road geometry for a single gps point buut rather for the link/road in which the gps point is. If you want to find get road geometry details for the links/roads of a particular route you can get it by using Fleet Telematics API. Adding "attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(TUNNEL,BRIDGE)" can fetch you the details whether the road is a tunnel or a bridge etc. Hope this helps!

http://cre.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&driver_cost=10&waypoint0=55.308989,10.805059&waypoint1=55.368920,11.288338&attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(TUNNEL,BRIDGE)

Comment: Thank you! So if I get premium account, it would be possible to get the adv data set that fall on the given route?